# Asynchronus timing issue in Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a simple Angular controller and a service as below. Problem is my service always returns null as it completes execution earlier than $http.get() success promise. This is common in language like JavaScript due to its asynchronus nature.

Can anyone please suggest what is best way to handle this in Angular application?

```
var app = angular.module('User', []);

app.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService){

  $scope.name = userService.getName();

}]);

app.service('userService', ['$http', function($http){

  getName = function(){
     var userName;
     $http.get('/api/user.json').success(function(data){
        userName = data.name;
     });
     return userName;
  }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your service, like this:

```
app.service('userService', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    getName: function(){return $http.get('/api/user.json');}
  }
}]);
```

And your controller, like this:

```
app.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService){
   userService.getName().success(function(data){
        $scope.name = data.name;
     });
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the resolve function in the router you are using. I typically use the UI.router but I believe the functionality is available in the default router as well. It's a way to ensure you have data prior to executing your controller code.